# Java GET request returns response twice

Tags: java, url, get

I'm trying to write a GET handler which can save the response to a file.

```
public String get(String[] args) throws IOException {
  URL url = new URL(args[1]);
  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
  String output = "";
  String line = input.readLine();
  while(line != null){
    output += line + "\n";
    line = input.readLine();
  }
  saveGetToFile(output);
  return "Response saved to: " + path.toString();
}
```

However it seems to always return the response twice. Is there some logic I'm missing here? It returns the entire response, followed by the entire response again.

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not know what `saveGetToFile(String)` does, nor what the `path` variable contains, we can not know what happens in those lines. But your code up until then is fine, except that you forget to close the stream.

```
public String get() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://httpbin.org/get");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } finally {
        if (reader!=null) {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
    saveGetToFile(builder.toString()); //Does this method modify the value of your variable 'path'?
    return "Response saved to: " + path.toString(); //Where do you write to path?
}
```

If you want, make a `System.out.println(builder.toString())` to verify that the code up until then works.

Answer (score -1):

try this and see if it works

```
public String get(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(args[1]);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(url.openStream())); 
    String output = "";
    String line;

    while((line=input.readLine())!= null){
        output += line + "\n";
    }

    saveGetToFile(output);
    return "Response saved to: " + path.toString();
}
```